# Multivariate, Multi-step LSTM time series forecast

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, prediction, forecast

I've been working on this [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/) from machine learning mastery website in order to implement a multivariate and multi-step code. Since the code is too large, you'll find the implementation as well as the dataset here: https://github.com/HudaBou/Pollution/blob/master/Pollution-Code.ipynb

How can I make sure that I'm predicting the Pollution column instead of an other column? I'm new to python, and it got me confused.

I was wondering if this is the part of the code where we define it :

```
# invert scaling for forecast
pred_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1)).fit(dataset.values[:,0].reshape(-1, 1)) 
inv_yhat = pred_scaler.inverse_transform(yhat)
print(inv_yhat.shape)
# invert scaling for actual
inv_y = pred_scaler.inverse_transform(test_y)
print(inv_y.shape)
```

Since running this part of the code only picks the first prediction (t+1) out of 6, Am I mistaken ? 
code:

```
inv_yhat = inv_yhat[:,0]
inv_y=inv_y[:,0]
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code *here*, not in some external repo (BTW, your link does not even lead to a single script).

Comment: I'll edit the post and add the code here (BTW, it leads to the repertory that contains the data as well as the code ;))

Comment: The code is too long, I updated the link so it leads to the code directly.

Answer (score 1):

In the section `Define and Fit Model`  in the [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/) you are following  you find the following code:

```
train_X, train_y = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
test_X, test_y = test[:, :-1], test[:, -1]
```

Here you see that the `y` column is the last `-1` column. A clearer way to do this is to do something like

```
col_to_predict = 'pollution'
train_X, train_y = train.drop(columns=[col_to_predict]), train[col_to_predict]
```

In this way you are sure that:

1. Your `y` column is `pollution` or whatever you decide, which is what you want
2. Your training set has all the variables beside your `y`

Comment: you can choose it as selected answer if it answers your question @Giselle

Comment: Hi @ DaveR, thank you for your answer, and I'm sorry for my late reply. Actually, I'm working on a multivariate and multistep forecast. However, I used your suggestion but doesn't work for me.. I suppose there is another way to do it. Thanks